# Добавление данных в текущий ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Всем привет. Такая проблема. Есть ArrayList() в котором хранятся текущие какие то текстовые сообщения. Список выводит адаптер.

**Вопрос:** Как добавить данные в ArrayList по нажатию на кнопку?

```
@Override
public void response(ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> response) {       // тут мои текущие данные

    int count = response.size() - 1;
    if(count > 0) {
        getEndMsgId = response.get(count).getNewMsg();
    }
        if(sAdapter == null) {
            sAdapter = new ChatMsgAdapter(this, response);
            listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Array:: setAdapter" + getEndMsgId);
        } else {
            sAdapter.setData(response);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Array:: setData" + getEndMsgId);
        }
}

public void sendMsg(View v) {                                 //кнопка

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.form_input);
    String form_input_msg = editText.getText().toString();

    if (!form_input_msg.equals("")) {
        GetMsg getMsg = new GetMsg();
        getMsg.SendMsg(getApplicationContext(), GET_ID, form_input_msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как ваш код относится к вопросу? Где здесь попытка добавления данных? Скорее всего вам надо лишь получить ссылку на List в адаптере и добавить данные методом addAll()

Comment: Ну так я и хочу у вас поинтересоваться, как это сделатб правильно? Мне нужно добавить данные, уже в существующий список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте в адаптере метод `addData(List<ResponseMsgArray> dataToAdd)`
2. В нём воспользуйтесь методом добавления данных в список `innerAdapterData.addAll(dataToAdd);`
3. Сразу после вызова этого метода уведомите адаптер о изменениях в нём методом `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: У меня уже есть в адаптере метод setData. В общем сама суть такова, я отправляю сообщения на сервер, и когда я нажимаю кнопку "отправить", хочу что бы введённый текст сразу же отобразился в адаптере

Comment: @sergei1094, этот ваш метод может быть сделан разными способами. Вы либо чистите уже имеющийся список и добавляете новые данные методом `addAll` или присваиваете переменной ссылку на новый список. Эти способы очень разные. Если вам надо добавить только один элемент в список, то замените в методе список на одну переменную и добавьте её через `add()`

Comment: Я понял ваше направление. Я всё понял и думаю что справлюсь. Спасибо вам